# Ruby on Rails website errors after VPS upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bluecloth

Our VPS was just upgraded from Debian Squeeze and php 5.2 to Ubuntu and php 5.5, our website (coded in Ruby) is now down with all sorts of fun errors:

our URL: http://grfxpstore.com/

Here's a link to what has changed: http://wiki.dreamhost.com/EOL_Debian_4.0,_5.0,_and_6.0_on_VPS#Overview

Unfortunately I'm not at all a web admin (actually a dba), and our former webmaster is not available for questioning!  Any help or assistance as to what is going on, if there are possible fixes (or not) would be greatly appreciated!

This is the error with backtrace:

```
undefined method `name' for "BlueCloth":String (NoMethodError)
/home/grfxp_edge/rails/grfxp_web/releases/20130606051836/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:277:in `=='
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:217:in `==='
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:217:in `matching_specs'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `find_all'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:410:in `each'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:409:in `each'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:216:in `find_all'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:216:in `matching_specs'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:238:in `to_specs'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1208:in `gem'
  /home/grfxp_edge/rails/grfxp_web/releases/20130606051836/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:75:in `add_load_paths'
  /home/grfxp_edge/rails/grfxp_web/releases/20130606051836/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:301:in `add_gem_load_paths'
  /home/grfxp_edge/rails/grfxp_web/releases/20130606051836/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:301:in `each'
  /home/grfxp_edge/rails/grfxp_web/releases/20130606051836/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:301:in `add_gem_load_paths'
  /home/grfxp_edge/rails/grfxp_web/releases/20130606051836/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:132:in `process'
  /home/grfxp_edge/rails/grfxp_web/releases/20130606051836/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
  /home/grfxp_edge/rails/grfxp_web/releases/20130606051836/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
  /home/grfxp_edge/rails/grfxp_web/releases/20130606051836/config/environment.rb:21
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
  /dh/passenger/helper-scripts/classic-rails-preloader.rb:96:in `preload_app'
  /dh/passenger/helper-scripts/classic-rails-preloader.rb:184
```

Comment: I highly doubt that the `PHP` version is at all relevant. I can't really debug your problem without more information, but the fact that it's running rails version `2.3.11` and ruby version `1.8` are a cause for concern! (When was the last time you updated the software??) MAYBE you just need to (re-) install the ruby gem dependencies: `cd  /home/grfxp_edge/rails/grfxp_web/releases/current; bundle install` ?...

Comment: You application is running on Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 2.3.11. This means your app hasn't been updated for more than 5 years. There are multiple security issues known in this versions. My advise is: hire a experienced Rails developer or freelancer as soon as possible. Even if you wee able to fix your current problem, your app is in danger...

Comment: @TomLord Bundler was introduced in Rails 3. Common Rails 2.3 do not have a Gemfile. What makes it very hard to figure out which old gem versions might work with that app...

Comment: Ahh yeah true, I forgot about that. It's been years since I last worked on a Rails 2.x application, after all! Well, my next guess is to check the `Passenger` configuration. (How was it configured before? Did you save a snapshot of the machine before upgrading the OS?) You may need to specify the ruby/gem home directory paths, or something.

Answer (score 0):

You should downgrade ruby gems:

```
$ gem install rubygems-update -v 1.3.5
$ update_rubygems --version=1.3.5
```

You may need the system administrator to do this for you if you don't have permissions.